# Using lateinit properties in constructor in kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

How can I use lateinit properties in my class constructor:

I have a spring component that I use to setup and access a third party library like so:

```
@Service
class LibProxy {

    @Value("\${lib.someProperty}")
    private lateinit var someProperty: String

    final var lib: Lib

    init {
        lib = Lib(someProperty)
    }
}
```

This gives a

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property someProperty has not been initialized
```

How is this supposed to be done?

I would like to avoid constructs like so:

```
@Service
class LibProxy {

    @Value("\${lib.someProperty}")
    private lateinit var someProperty: String

    private var lib: Lib? = null

    getLib(): Lib {
        if (lib == null) {
            lib = Lib(someProperty)
        }
        return lib ?: Lib(someProperty)
    }
}
```

Comment: well because lateinit will be initialized after object construction (call to init) you can' use it. You should go with class LibProxy(@Value val someProperty: String)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [JEY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1976843/jey)'s comment. This is how it is supposed to be done:

```
@Service
class LibProxy(@Value("\${lib.someProperty}") private val someProperty: String) {

    final var lib: Lib

    init {
        lib = Lib(someProperty)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI there is no final keyword in Kotlin

Comment: @Strelok: Sure there is a final keyword in Kotlin. The above code will not build without it.

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities here:

The easy one is to replace the `init` block with a `@PostConstruct` method.  Spring will call this once, after the object has been constructed (and hence autowired values are all set).  For example:

```
@PostConstruct
private fun initialise() {
    lib = Lib(someProperty)
}
```

The other is to arrange for the autowired property to be passed in a constructor, not set as a property (as per other answers).

One approach that works well, especially if you have several configuration properties, is to have a central class storing them:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("lib")
class ConfigProperties {
    var someProperty = "defaultValue"
    // …and other properties…
}
```

This will set `someProperty` from a "lib.someProperty" value in a config file (or left as "defaultValue" if not present).

You can then autowire its instance in the constructor, e.g.:

```
class SomeService @Autowired constructor(
    private val configProperties: ConfigProperties) {

    init {
        lib = Lib(configProperties.someProperty)
    }
}
```

(Centralising the properties can make it easier to find what properties are available, too.)